# find object with greatest number of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have written a function which will return a name with the greatest number of children from a contact list (array of objects), but it is limited to the number of elements I include in the if statement. How can I make it go over all the elements in this contact list, regardless of size? I tried to make a for of loop, but it won't let me sort through elements using a counter "I", returning an error.

Thanks in advance!

```js
let contacts = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    children:
      [
        { name: 'Mary', age: 11 }
      ]
  }, {
    name: 'Franklin',
    children:
      [
        { name: 'Susy', age: 7 },
        { name: 'Tom', age: 5 }
      ]
  }
];

function p_w_m_children(arr){
  let person_w_most_children = "";
  arr.sort((elem_1, elem_2) => {
    if (elem_1.children > elem_2.children){
      person_w_most_children = elem_1.name;
    }else{
      person_w_most_children = elem_2.name;
    }
  });
  return person_w_most_children;
}

console.log("The person who has most children is " + p_w_m_children(contacts)+ ".");
```

Comment: Firstly, your comparison (`elem_1.children > elem_2.children`) is not valid. Using that snippet will not compare the length of the two `children` arrays. Instead you need to use `elem_1.children.length > elem_2.children.length`. I'm not 100% sure but I believe your current solution will implicitly convert the arrays to strings and sort them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and keep a record of the contact who has the most children. Replace that record with the current one in the loop if the number of children is greater.

Then return that contact when the loop is finished.

```js
let contacts = [{
  name: 'John',
  children: [{
    name: 'Mary',
    age: 11
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Franklin',
  children: [{
      name: 'Susy',
      age: 7
    },
    {
      name: 'Tom',
      age: 5
    }
  ]
}];

function p_w_m_children(arr) {
  let person_w_most_children;

  contacts.forEach(contact => {
    if (!person_w_most_children || contact.children.length > person_w_most_children.children.length) {
      person_w_most_children = contact;
    }

  })


  return person_w_most_children;
}

console.log("The person who has most children is " + p_w_m_children(contacts).name + ".");
```

---

Same as above without using `forEach` :

```js
let contacts = [{
  name: 'John',
  children: [{
    name: 'Mary',
    age: 11
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Franklin',
  children: [{
      name: 'Susy',
      age: 7
    },
    {
      name: 'Tom',
      age: 5
    }
  ]
}];

function p_w_m_children(arr) {
  let person_w_most_children;

  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (!person_w_most_children || contacts[i].children.length > person_w_most_children.children.length) {
      person_w_most_children = contacts[i];
    }
  }


  return person_w_most_children;
}

console.log("The person who has most children is " + p_w_m_children(contacts).name + ".");
```

Comment: Many thanks! is there a way to do it without using forEach? I can't use it for this exercise.

Comment: I've added an example without using `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

To find the person with the most children using arr.sort, you can use the following:

```
arr.sort((elem_1, elem_2) => {
    return elem_1.children.length - elem_2.children.length
}
```

The key points being that you compare the `.length` of the arrays (rather than just comparing the arrays themselves) and that the `.sort` callback returns a value that can be sorted. The return is positive when `elem_1.children.length > elem_2.children.length`, negative when `elem_1.children.length < elem_2.children.length` and 0 when they are equal. This means the sort function can order the array correctly.

Then, once the array is sorted you can simply get the last element in the sorted array (the element with the largest value).

**Edit for Clarification**

```
let sortedArr = arr.sort((elem_1, elem_2) => {
    return elem_1.children.length - elem_2.children.length;
};
return sortedArr[sortedArr.length - 1].name;
```

Comment: Many thanks! but how do I get the name from the contact list? And apparently this will still only work with two elements, what I wanted was for it to work with any number of elements in the contact list.

Comment: This will work with any number of contacts. Firstly it *sorts the list of contacts*, so now you have a list of any number of contacts, sorted by amount of children, you simply need to access the name of the *last element in the sorted array*.

Comment: I've added a sample for clarification to my answer which shows how to get the name of the element with the most children from the sorted list.